# Why React batch not working in async callback

Tags: reactjs

I'm using **React "version": "18.2.0"** which must support [batching](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) everywhere(in callback, in setTimeout and in Promises).

I have redux store which looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
};

const accessSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'access',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

I have react component which renders route(from **react-router v5**) only if we do not have **token** in redux store and if we do not have token this component redirects us to root page:

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { tokenSelector } from '../redux/slices/access';

const UnauthorizedRoute = ({ exact, path, children }) => {
  // we get token from redux store
  const token = useSelector(tokenSelector);


    return (
      <Route
        exact={exact}
        path={path}
      >
        {token ? children : <Redirect to="/" />}
      </Route>
    };
};
```

Then we have **LoginPage** component which we render like this:

```
<UnauthorizedRoute exact path="/login">
    <LoginPage />
</UnauthorizedRoute>
```

In **LoginPage** component on form submit I have callback which looks like this:

```
const handleOnSubmit = async (formValues) => {
  const token = await backendApi.getToken(formValues);

  dispatch(setToken(token));
  history.push('/welcome-page');
}

<LoginForm
    onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
/>
```

I expect that react will rerender application only once after these code executes

```
  dispatch(setToken(token));
  history.push('/welcome-page');
```

In other words I expect that react will batch these two function calls(first call dispatches redux action and second call redirects us to welcome page). But in reality after executing this code user is redirected to root page **'/'** because it looks like after executing these **dispatch** and **history.push** **UnauthorizedRoute** component gets new token from redux store and redirects us to root page **'/'**.

But if change **handleSubmit** callback like this(we do not go to backend and use fake token):

```
const handleOnSubmit = async (formValues) => {
      dispatch(setToken('faketoken'));
      history.push('/welcome-page');
    }
    
    <LoginForm
        onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
    />
```

all works! user is redirected to '/welcome-page' and in **redux store token** value is **'faketoken'**

Maybe somebody knows how to fix it? I tried to wrap these code using **unstable_batchedUpdates** but it does not help

```
unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
      dispatch(setToken(token));
      history.push('/welcome-page');
});
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you are getting the default batching behavior but this isn't what you want? You ***want*** the dispatched action to ***fully*** process so the updated Redux state is available later when you navigate to a protected route! In other words you ***don't*** want these updates to be batched. This is explained a bit further down in Gaearon's post in the "What if I don’t want to batch?" section.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but this code fixed the issue:

```
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

flushSync(() => {
  dispatch(setToken(token));
  history.push('/welcome-page');
});
```